# Animate fontawesome Icon inside anchor tag to fly in onhover

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, font-awesome

I'm in need for a CSS/SCSS/SASS guru to help me determine what I am doing wrong with this simple animation.

**Objective:** What I'm trying to accomplish a simple animation in which the fontawesome icon `fa-angle-right` fly in from the left after the word, onHover. I figured this could be done with a `display: none` property and adding some `transition` to the parent property, but it's not animating as intended.

The caveat here is that I CANNOT change the HTML structure.

[An example of what I'm trying to do](https://codepen.io/nicholaspetersen/pen/mEmOjb); but granted this is using a different HTML structure & SVG instead of fontawesome icons

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/bwrmam9o/1/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn ripple">
     <i class="fa fa-left fa-location-arrow"></i> 
     <span class="label">View Location </span>
     <i class="fa fa-right fa-angle-right fa-animate"></i>
</a>
```

**SCSS/SASS**

```
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #CB5039;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.08, 0.355, 1);
  .fa-left{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .fa-right{
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .fa-animate{
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.08, 0.355, 1);
  }
  &:hover{
    background: blue;
    .fa-animate{
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}

.ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.ripple:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #FFF 10%, transparent 10.01%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  transform: scale(10, 10);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .25s, opacity 1s;
}
.ripple:active:after {
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  opacity: .2;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want? modify style like this .

```
.fa-animate{
 left: -15px;
 position:relative;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 1s;
}
&:hover{
 background: blue;
 .fa-animate{
  left: 0;
  opacity:1;
 }
}
```

full edited code here : https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/bwrmam9o/3/

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: happy to help you

Comment: I did find a small issue, as the button is bigger and the text looks off center. Is there a way to give the arrow a `display: none` and animate that in, along with the expanding button?

Comment: using `display: none`  you can't animate . but you can use `visibility: hidden;` insted of `display:none`

Comment: will `visibility: hidden` close the extra gap on the right side due to the arrow markup?

Comment: if u want to center the text use `.btn{text-align:center}` . . and for clarification do you want the width of button to  increase when hover occurs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. the width would expand to accommodate the arrow flying in

Comment: i have updated my jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/bwrmam9o/4/ can u check it